# VBS - Copy all cells containing string to another sheet

Tags: vbscript

I have searched for over an hour looking for what I think is a simple task.

I have an Excel 2010 workbook with 2 sheets. In the first sheet, I have 1 column (A) with a couple thousand rows. They are arranged like this:

```
1 Title: aaaaa
2 Author: xxxxx
3 
4 Title: bbbbb
5 Author: yyyyy
6 
7 Title: ccccc
8 Author: zzzzz
9 
10 etc.....
```

I want to copy the cells into the 2nd sheet so it looks like this in 2 columns:

```
1 Title: aaaaa     Author: xxxxx
2 Title: bbbbb     Author: yyyyy
3 Title: ccccc     Author: zzzzz
```

It seems really simple, but I don't know VBS well at all. I need to search for cells that start with "Title" and copy that cell into column A of the other sheet. Then I need to search for cells that start with "Author" and copy that cell into column B of the other sheet.

Thanks,
Jono

Comment: Do you need to do this just once, or do you need to do it multiple times? Reason I ask is because if it's just once, you can use a filter and copy and paste...

Comment: Jaycal - I'm just doing this once, and now I feel a little bit foolish. Filters will make it much easier. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I just tried using filters, but I'd have to click a LOT of checkboxes. Is there a way to filter all cells that start with a certain string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a custom Text filter, select the filter of your column A, and then select Text Filter > Begins with

Then type "Title: ", but without the quotes. Hit enter and that should filter all your Titles. Copy and paste than, and the do the same for "Author: "